# Smack UserSearchManager getValues from Search and put into ListView

Tags: android, listview, search, smack

i have a big problem. My search with UserSearchManager is working fine but i dont understand how i put the results of the search in my list view.

The result type from the search is saved at a list and i wanna take the values from the row and put the result of the row in my list View in Android, but i dont get it, how i should start?

So i hope you can help me.

Moreover a have an another problem with the Iterator.

Android Studio say it cannot resolve the problem and a cast wont help me.

```
Iterator<Row> it = resultData.getRows();
Row row = it.next();
Iterator iterator = row.getValues("jid");
```

This lines are the problem. In many other threads, people have the same code snippets and theres working, but for me not.

Here is my complete code.

```
package de.hsrt.campusapp.app.module.xmppchat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.IQ;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.ProviderManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.iqregister.packet.Registration;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.search.ReportedData;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.search.UserSearchManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.xdata.Form;
import org.jxmpp.jid.DomainBareJid;
import org.jxmpp.jid.impl.JidCreate;
import org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringprepException;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import de.hsrt.campusapp.app.CampusAppConstants;
import de.hsrt.campusapp.app.R;



public class ActivitySearchContact extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String serverDomain = "search.ewcexmpp1";
    private static DomainBareJid serverDomainBareJid;
    private ReportedData resultData;
    private ListView contactList;
    private EditText contactName;
    private ImageButton searchContact;
    private XMPPTCPConnection con = CampusAppConstants.xmppController.getNetworkManager().getXmppTCPConnection();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_contact);
        contactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewForSearchAnswer);
        contactName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextContactInput);
        searchContact = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_searchContactDetail);


        searchContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String strContact = contactName.getText().toString();
                userSearch(strContact);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Diese Methode soll mir alle gesuchten Kontakte zurückliefern
     *
     * @return
     */

    public ReportedData userSearch(String searchname) {



        //hier eventuell die campusappconstants mit der verbindung benutzen
        UserSearchManager userSearchManager = new UserSearchManager(con);
        try {

            Form searchForm = userSearchManager.getSearchForm(getServerDomainBareJid());
            //erstellt die antwort form
            Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();
            //die eigentliche suche, ich suche in der spalte Username 
            answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);
            answerForm.setAnswer("search", searchname);


            //hier hol ich das ergebnis
            this.resultData = userSearchManager.getSearchResults(answerForm, getServerDomainBareJid());
            Toast.makeText(this, resultData.getRows().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(resultData.getRows() != null)
            {
                Iterator<Row> it = resultData.getRows();
                while(it.hasNext())
                {
                    Row row = it.next();
                    Iterator iterator = row.getValues("jid");
                    if(iterator.hasNext())
                    {
                        String value = iterator.next().toString();
                        Log.i("Iteartor values......"," "+value);
                    }
                    //Log.i("Iteartor values......"," "+value);
                }
                Toast.makeText(this,"Username Exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

         }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                e.getMessage();
                //Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName().toString(), "Fehler bei der Suche", e);
            }

            return this.resultData;
        }


    private static DomainBareJid getServerDomainBareJid() {
        try {
            serverDomainBareJid = JidCreate.domainBareFrom(serverDomain);
        } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return serverDomainBareJid;
    }
}
```

Comment: add the exception please

Comment: what version of smack are you using? Probably I understood your problem...